# Kotlin: Log.i() printing only 2 elements from 53-element array

Tags: android, for-loop, kotlin

I want to iterate through my ArrayList named parts, here is my code:

```
for(x in parts.indices){
            Log.i("INFO", parts.indices.toString())
        }
```

The output is the following:

```
0..52
0..52
```

But I'd expect 0..52 to be printed 53 times. I've tried changing `x in parts.indices` to `x in 0 until parts.size`, but the output remains the same. Interestingly enough, when I use the same construction in another class with the same imports it works ok. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `0..52` .... looping 53 times..0,1,2...52

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. It's probably on the level of log output, not program logic. `(0..52).toList().also { parts -> for (x in parts.indices) println(parts.indices) }` -- prints `0..52` 53 times.

Comment: What's the reason for iterating over indices instead of using `parts.forEach()`?

Comment: @Pawel I just need the indices to perform some calculations later on

Comment: @A.W. Use `parts.map { indices }` then.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Log issue, as noted by @Marko Topolnik, it seems to be 'folding' the output when strings are identical. Println does it as well, but at least prints a message saying `'identical 51 lines'`.